# Text special character in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to test various columns together according to their header instead of column numbers. If any cell of selected column contains text, special character and alphanumeric values the macro should pop up the cell address as an error.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Test()
     Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' here instead of mentioning C or D i want to mention Column Header
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row  ' here instead of mentioning C or D i want to mention Column Header

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("C" & i).Value = a-z or "SpecialCharacters"Then 
            msgbox "Error in " & i & "Row of C"
        elseif Range("D" & i).Value = a-z or "SpecialCharacters"Then 
            msgbox "Error in " & i & "Row of D"
        else
            Msgbox "No error in column C" ' instead of C it should show Header name 
            Msgbox "No error in column D"  ' instead of C it should show Header name   
        end if
```

[image]

I appreciate your time and efforts. please don't use any **function** to do so because i have further code too to run and using **function** it becomes a bit difficult. Here c2,c3,c4,last cell of column c and all blanks should not be considered as an error.

Comment: so as a hint: `If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value) Then` checks if the value is a number (blanks are considered as `0` which is a number). And there is no built in way to use header names instead of columns. But you can search for that header in row 1 and determine the column number where it was found and then use this column number. But this won't work without using functions then.

Comment: Data set up as a table might allow use of "header"

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below by using Find to locate Header Name. In below example I have assumed headers are in row 1:

```
    lngCheckCol = Range("1:1").Find("HeaderName", , , xlWhole).Column
    LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, lngCheckCol).END(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thanks !! To select Header name this macro is working absolutely fine but to validate the cell contains text, special character and alphanumeric values  or not i guess you need to add something ?.

Comment: @Coolmunda As I already said in my first comment with `IsNumeric` like `If IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value) Then` you can check if the value is numeric or not. So that should be all you need. So we left a little work for you: Everything you need to build your code is on the table already. Just put all these things together and you got your desired behavior.